# ¿Cómo hacer que un h1 aparezca con una transición al presionar un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Necesito que el contenido de mi h1 aparezca de manera no tan brusca al presionar mi button, intenté poniéndole una transición, desapareciendo el elemento y después volviéndolo a aparecer con Javascript, pero no resultó.

```js
function saludo(){
  document.getElementById('hola').style.display="inline";
}
```

```css
h1{
  display: none;
  transition: 10s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="practica.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="resultado" onclick="saludo()">resultado</button>
<h1 id="hola">Hola colombiaaaaaaaa</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que sea efectiva `transition` necesita que la propiedad sea graduable, `display` tiene o un estado o otro pero no se puede graduar. En tu caso te recomiendo que uses `opacity` que tiene una escala *0-1*

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```js
function saludo(){
  document.getElementById('hola').style.opacity="1";
}
```

```css
h1{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 10s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="practica.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="resultado" onclick="saludo()">resultado</button>
<h1 id="hola">Hola colombiaaaaaaaa</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Y en el caso de que quiera hacerlo con getElementsByClassName qué debería hacer?

Comment: En el caso de clases cambia la funcion de javascript por ->  document.getElementsByClassName('hola')[0].style.opacity="1";

Answer (score 0):

Te hice algunos retoques:

**1-** En el JS, ahora la funcion `saludo()` primero elimina la clase `hola` (que agregué en el `HTML`) y luego agrega la clase `aparece`.

**2-** En el `CSS`, la clase **hola** solamente mantendrá escondido el div con las propiedades `visibility` y `opacity`.
Mientras que la clase **aparece** modificará estas dos propiedades, y lo hará con un delay de 0s para la propiedad `visibility` y con un delay de 1s para la propiedad `opacity`.

```js
 function saludo(){
      document.getElementById('hola').classList.remove('hola');
      document.getElementById('hola').classList.add('aparece');
    }
```

```css
    .hola{
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      }

    
.aparece{
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: visibility 0s, opacity 1s linear;      
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="practica.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="resultado" onclick="saludo()">resultado</button>
    <h1 id="hola" class="hola">Hola colombiaaaaaaaa</h1>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```